# Show component when onClick method is called

Tags: reactjs, components, devexpress

I have imported a schedular component from devexpress and have modified the appointments in this with the constant MyAppointment. Now i want to be able to delete and modify apointment data with a dialog when clicking on these. Therefore i added an onClick method to the MyAppointment const and tried to return the dialog however nothing happens when pressing the appointments.

```
const MyAppointment = ({ children, style, ...restProps }) => {

 return (
 <Appointments.Appointment
  {...restProps}
  style={{
    ...style,
    backgroundColor: "#a02d37",
    borderRadius: "8px",
  }} 
   onClick={()=>{
     return (
       <SimpleDialogDemo />
       )
    }}
   >
  {children}
  </Appointments.Appointment>
  );
 }





const emails = ['username@gmail.com', 'user02@gmail.com'];

function SimpleDialog(props) {
const { onClose, selectedValue, open } = props;

 const handleClose = () => {
   onClose(selectedValue);
  };

 const handleListItemClick = (value) => {
   onClose(value);
 };

 return (
    <Dialog onClose={handleClose} open={open}>
    <DialogTitle>Set backup account</DialogTitle>
    <List sx={{ pt: 0 }}>
      {emails.map((email) => (
        <ListItem button onClick={() => handleListItemClick(email)} key={email}>
          <ListItemAvatar>
            <Avatar sx={{ bgcolor: blue[100], color: blue[600] }}>
              <PersonIcon />
            </Avatar>
          </ListItemAvatar>
          <ListItemText primary={email} />
        </ListItem>
      ))}

    <ListItem autoFocus button onClick={() => handleListItemClick('addAccount')}>
      <ListItemAvatar>
        <Avatar>
          <AddIcon />
         </Avatar>
        </ListItemAvatar>
       <ListItemText primary="Add account" />
      </ListItem>
     </List>
    </Dialog>
   );
  }

  SimpleDialog.propTypes = {
  onClose: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  open: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
  selectedValue: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  };

 export default function SimpleDialogDemo() {
  const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(true);
  const [selectedValue, setSelectedValue] = React.useState(emails[1]);

 const handleClickOpen = () => {
 setOpen(true);
 };

 const handleClose = (value) => {
   setOpen(false);
   setSelectedValue(value);
 };

handleClickOpen();

return (
  <div>
    <SimpleDialog
      selectedValue={selectedValue}
      open={open}
      onClose={handleClose}
    />
   </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 onClick={()=>{
     return (
       <SimpleDialogDemo />
       )
    }}
```

isn't actually doing anything. All you're doing is returning a component in an event handler that doesn't do anything with that return value. The onClick event handler is react-agnostic.

If you want to display a component when something is clicked, you'll need to use local state variables to show/hide it based on a click action like below:

```
const MyAppointment = ({ children, style, ...restProps }) => {
 const [showDialog, setShowDialog] = useState(false);

 return (
 <Appointments.Appointment
  {...restProps}
  style={{
    ...style,
    backgroundColor: "#a02d37",
    borderRadius: "8px",
  }} 
   onClick={()=> setShowDialog(true)}
   >
  {children}
  {showDialog && <SimpleDialogDemo onClose=(() => setShowDialog(false))/>}
  </Appointments.Appointment>
  );
 }
```

Note the onClose prop I added to your SimpleDialog component so that you have a way of setting the showDialog state back to hidden (you will need to add this propr if you use it).